# display videos from specific folder from sd card in listview are in Gridview

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I am trying to populate a listview with video files from a folder created on sd card. I use:

```
managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, mystring, null, null, null);
```

But it populates all videos saved in sdcard, but I want only those videos which are saved in a specific folder.